# check if client click on image which is defined only in CSS file like background of class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to check via javascript if client click on background image which is defined in css file to some div class ? ..

```
.volume {
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    background: url(../img/speaker.png) left center no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

I really don t want to change HTML file because I am not an owner..

here is the HTML code

```
  <div class="volume">
                <div class="progress-bar">
                    <div class="progress">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can bind a click event to the whole volume div, sure, though determining if it falls within the background image is a bit trickier but can be done!

Comment: By "clicking the background image", do you mean just anywhere on the `.volume` div or do you mean on the non-transparent parts of that image?

Comment: What's PHP got to do with this?

Comment: I need to implement mute function...so the volume go to the zero ...but i dont need to click anywhere on the div ..but only on the speaker icon ..and I am worry about that is not possible ..but thats the reason why I am asking ..so I wait some hours to if somebody have som good idea ..and if there is no chance to do it ..I have to edit that HTML and add image to HTML not to CSS ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this simply by placing a transparent element over the speaker icon, and assigning a click event to it.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjh42/ukk8dan8/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .volume {
                width: 40%;
                margin: auto;
                padding-left: 40px;
                /*background: url(../img/speaker.png) left center no-repeat;*/
                background: url(http://findicons.com/files/icons/1672/mono/32/speaker.png) left center no-repeat;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                margin-top: 2em;
            }

            #overlay {
                z-index: 1000;
                background-color: transparent;
                height: 32px;
                width: 32px;
                position: relative;
                right:40px;
                bottom:2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="volume">
            <div class="progress-bar">
                <div class="progress">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay""></div>').click(function() { overlay_click(); } );
            $('div.volume').prepend($overlay);

            function overlay_click() {
                alert('icon was clicked');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks that works good ...I just need to update some CSS row styling but its good :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what / how this looks on your end, but if you wish to check if a user clicked on the .volume div (and not the .progress-bar or .progress), you can simply check the `target` of the click event:

```
var volume = document.querySelector('.volume');
volume.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // check if it was the .volume div
  if (e.target.className === 'volume') {
    // do something
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j64fpb3m/1/